# Nginx: "directive is not allowed here"

Tags: nginx, include, directive

I have a standard enough nginx conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf which has a server block that includes another file, e.g.

```
server {
  ...
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-redirects.conf;
  ...
}
```

The nginx-redirects.conf file, as the name suggests, just does a long list of redirects, e.g.

```
rewrite  ^/.../.../...$ https://www.example.com/.../.../... permanent;
rewrite  ^/.../.../...$ https://www.example.com/.../.../... permanent;
...
```

But when I restart nginx, I get the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] "rewrite" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-redirects.conf:1 nginx: configuration file
>   /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

I tried encapsulating my long list of redirects in nginx-redirects.conf in a location / block but I got the same error with "location" instead of "rewrite". I then tried encapsulating the location / block in a server block but I got the same error with "server" instead of "location".

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Placing it in the `conf.d` directory is a bad idea. You will probably find that some other config file (either `nginx.conf` or `default`) is just pulling in all of those files and sucking yours in at the same time into the wrong context.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks! The /etc/nginx/nginx.conf was saying to include all *.conf files in the /etc/nginx/conf.d  directory. I put the nginx-redirects.conf file in a different directory and it worked.

Comment: @RichardSmith could you please make it an answer proper? This way others, like me, would find it most easily. Especially interesting as it sounds counter intuitive but with the right context makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and the answer is as stated in the comments - config files in the `conf.d` directory are being included from `nginx.conf`. This means that the `rewrite` directive is trying to be used within a `http {}` block which isn't allowed.

The solution is to put site-specific config files elsewhere. Since `nginx.conf` only includes files directly in that directory, yours can be in a subdirectory, for example `/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites/mysite-redirects.conf`